# calculate the product of two input fields in javascript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that I want to populate with the product of two input fields that appear earlier in the form.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="item_name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Item:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" name="item_qty[]" placeholder="Quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" name="item_price[]" placeholder="Price">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text" name="item_total[]" placeholder="Total">
    </div>
</div>
```

These input fields can occur multiple times, so I'm attempting to loop over the `item_total[]` arrray and attach a listener to the focus event.

```
$.each($("[name='item_total[]']"), function( index, value ) {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        var value = ?
        //not sure how to select the value of the two previous input fields
        // var value =  $("item_qty[index]") * $("item_price[index]");
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: instead focus of total textbox do the calculation on change of qty and price text boxes

Comment: once I've got it working here I'll refactor it to respond to change events - thanks

Comment: I added the answer, have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can do like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fvJCE)

```
  $('input[name="item_qty[]"],input[name="item_price[]"]').on("change",function (){
    var $container = $(this).closest('.form-group');
      qty = Number($('input[name="item_qty[]"]',$container).val())||0,
      price = Number($('input[name="item_price[]"]',$container).val())||0;

    $('input[name="item_total[]"]',$container).val(qty * price);

  })
```

Another solution starts with selector:

```
  $('input[name^="item_qty"],input[name^="item_price"]').on("change",function (){
    var $container = $(this).closest('.form-group');
      qty = Number($('input[name^="item_qty"]',$container).val())||0,
      price = Number($('input[name^="item_price"]',$container).val())||0;

    $('input[name^="item_total"]',$container).val(qty * price);

  })
```

Comment: How would i tell the difference between the multiple occurrences of each selector. My form has several rows of the above input fields, so `$('input[name="item_qty[]"]')` is not specific enough ?

Comment: I've added the scope to div.form-group

Comment: FYI...Added another solution with `starts with` selector, you can manage without subscripts it'll work for `name[], name[0], name[1]...`

Answer (score 1):

Following assumes that you have `[]` in input names due to repeating rows and will isolate values within repeated row instances

You can traverse to the nearest wrapping container which would be  `form-group` using `closest()`, then look within that container using `find()`

I think what you want is to apply change handler to the user inputs and calculate total when they change

```
$("input[name=item_qty\\[\\]], input[name=item_price\\[\\]]").change(function(){
    var $container = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    var qty = $container.find('[name=item_qty\\[\\]]') || 0;
    var price = $container.find('[name=item_price\\[\\]]') || 0;
    $container.find('[name=item_total\\[\\]]').val( qty * price );                                  

});
```

jQuery requires escaping special characters in selectors which is why there are so many `\\` above.

See escaping rules in **[selectors API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

Comment: You're correct about repeatig rows of input, this is almost there I think, but the `item_total[]` needs to be specific to that row of inputs.

Comment: it is , assuming that the `form-group` is the repeated row

Comment: Got ya. thanks for clearing that up - so the scope of the find is only elements within this row, rather than within the entire page? - what does the `|| 0;` achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following would work.

```
var quantityEl = $('input[name="item_qty[]"]'),
    priceEl = $('input[name="item_price[]"]'),
    totalEl = $('input[name="item_total[]"]')
;

var calculateTotal = function() {
    var quantity = +quantityEl.val().trim(),
        price = +priceEl.val().trim(),
        total = quantity * price
    ;

    if (!isNaN(total)) {
        totalEl.val(total);
    }     
};

priceEl.on('change keyup paste', calculateTotal);
quantityEl.on('change keyup paste', calculateTotal);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do soemthing like this

```
input1 = $(this).closest($("[name='item_price']")).val()
```

Or like this

```
input1 = $("[name='item_price']")[index]).val()
```

Comment: `closest` doesn't work like that, it only looks at ancestors, second version is invalid syntax